# I keep getting the Type Error 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: tuples, typeerror, slice

Here is my code, I'm new to coding so I am just trying out the basics of the slice function.

webiste = "http://google.com"

slice = slice(7,-4)

print(website[slice])

I was expecting to get the result google but instead I got an Type Error 'tuple' is not callable.

Comment: Is this Python code? Your code has `slice(7,-4)` which is calling a function `slice`. Based on the error, you probably assigned `slice` to a tuple in a previous line of code (which is not shown here), so `slice` is now a tuple and you are trying to call it like a function. Try to print out what `slice` is before calling it and check some of the names for your variables.